# How to optimize a search in coq

Tags: optimization, coq

I have a simple search function for a property
that I am interested in, and a proof that the function is correct.  I want to evaluate the function, and use the correctness proof to get the theorem for the original property.  Unfortunately, evaluation in coq is very slow.  As a trivial example, consider looking for square roots:

```
(*
Coq 8.4
A simple example to demonstrate searching.
Timings are rough and approximate.
*)

Require Import Peano_dec.

Definition SearchSqrtLoop :=
  fix f i n := if eq_nat_dec (i * i) n
  then i
  else match i with
  | 0 => 0  (* ~ Square n \/ n = 0 *)
  | S j => f j n
  end
.

Definition SearchSqrt n := SearchSqrtLoop n n.

(*
Compute SearchSqrt 484.
takes about 30 seconds.
*)

Theorem sqrt_484a : SearchSqrt 484 = 22.
  apply eq_refl. (* 100 seconds *)
Qed.  (* 50 seconds *)

Theorem sqrt_484b : SearchSqrt 484 = 22.
  vm_compute.  (* 30 seconds *)
  apply eq_refl.
Qed.  (* 30 seconds *)

Theorem sqrt_484c (a : nat) : SearchSqrt 484 = 22.
  apply eq_refl.  (* 100 seconds *)
Qed.  (* 50 seconds *)

Theorem sqrt_484d (a : nat) : SearchSqrt 484 = 22.
  vm_compute.  (* 60 seconds *)
  apply eq_refl.
Qed.  (* 60 seconds *)
```

Now try the corresponding function in Python:

```
def SearchSqrt(n):
  for i in range(n, -1, -1):
    if i * i == n:
      return i
  return 0
```

or slightly more literally

```
def SearchSqrtLoop(i, n):
  if i * i == n:
    return i
  if i == 0:
    return 0
  return SearchSqrtLoop(i - 1, n)

def SearchSqrt(n):
  return SearchSqrtLoop(n, n)
```

The function is nearly instant in Python, but takes minutes in coq, depending on exactly how you try to call it.  Also curious is that putting an extra variable in makes vm_compute take twice as long.

I understand that everything is done symbolically in coq, and thus slow, but it would be very useful if I could directly evaluate simple functions.  Is there a way to do it?  Just using native integers instead of linked lists would probably help a lot.

Comment: Nowadays, it takes 0.6 - 3.6 seconds on my machine with Coq 8.5pl3 with literally the same code. The speedup for `apply eq_refl` (from `sqrt_484a`) is really impressive -- it takes 0.6 s.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get a speedup if you use binary arithmetic instead of unary arithmetic. Take a look at NArith and ZArith.

http://coq.inria.fr/library/

You'll also get a speedup if you run your code on OCaml, Haskell, or Scheme instead.

http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual025.html

Comment: I'm aware of binary arithmetic.  I also know I can run the program in another language, as shown in the Python example.  But, if I run it in another language, how do I get it back into Coq as a proof?  Or do I just make it an Axiom after the other program returns success?  Still, even extracted programs use odd representations of integers instead of native ones.  Is there a way to automatically convert a function of nat to a function of N?  Is there any system that would try to optimize it closer to native?  I guess, I'm asking: can I compile an expression and have Coq trust the result?

Comment: What I meant was, for testing, you can automatically convert your Coq code for `SearchSqrt` into OCaml code using extraction, but you can't convert `sqrt_484a`, because `Prop`s and dependency in types get erased. There's no automatic way of optimizing or converting a function of `nat` to a function of `N`. To obtain speeds similar to those of hardware, the naturals need to be implemented as a 32-tuple of bits. Take a look at `NatInt`, `Cyclic`, `Natural`, and `Integer`. Coq isn't meant for proving `SearchSqrt 484 = 22`. It's meant for proving `forall n, SearchSqrt (n * n) = n`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much more efficient function for finding square roots in the standard library ([`sqrt`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Nat.html#sqrt)):

> The following square root function is linear (and tail-recursive). With Peano representation, we can't do better. For faster algorithm, see `Psqrt`/`Zsqrt`/`Nsqrt`...

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.

Theorem sqrt_484a_v2 : sqrt 484 = 22.
  Time apply eq_refl.
Time Qed.
```

As `Time` tells us it works much faster (around 200 times faster than `sqrt_484a`).

The reason for this performance difference lies in the fact that `SearchSqrt` squares its first argument on each iteration, which is an expensive operation.

`sqrt`'s implementation, on the other hand, is based on the [Odd Number Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddNumberTheorem.html) (1 + 3 + 5 + ... is a square number). One just needs to count the number of increasing intervals that can be fitted into the input argument `n` and that would be the [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) of `n`. E.g. 22 = (1 + 3 + 5 + 7) + 6, which means there are 4 intervals (of lengths `1`, `3`, `5`, and `7`) in 22, so `sqrt 22 = 4` (and we are not interested in the residual value 6).